# Particle simulator Java

Tags: java, swing

I know i am doing something wrong, but i cant find what exactly (long day of coding).

I need to implement particle simulator.
I have some classes and i need to make it possible to create few emitters on right click.

some code:

```
public final class Viewport extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

  private AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
  private ArrayList particleList = new ArrayList();
  ParticleEmitter emitter1;
  private Timer timer;
  double x;
  double y;

  public Viewport() {
    particalEmitterImport();
  }


  public void particalEmitterImport() {

    initComponents();
    timer = new Timer(30, this);
    emitter1 = new ParticleEmitter(3);
    timer.start();
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    //repaint();
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    transform.setToIdentity();
  }

  public void particalEmitterImport(int mouseX, int mouseY) {

    initComponents();
    timer = new Timer(30, this);
    emitter1 = new ParticleEmitter(3);
    timer.start();
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);

    x = mouseX;
    y = mouseY;
    transform.setToIdentity();
  }
```

---

main class:

```
private void viewportMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    Viewport vw = new Viewport();
    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt)) {
        xMouse = evt.getX();
        yMouse = evt.getY();
        vw.particalEmitterImport(xMouse, xMouse);
        vw.setLocation(xMouse,yMouse);
        System.out.println("CLICK");
        System.out.println(xMouse);
        System.out.println(yMouse);
        vw.setVisible(true);
    }
```

The problem is i can't see my emitter, but in output i see all values that i get from event.

Comment: Why are you creating a new viewport (`Viewport vw = new Viewport();`) instead of modifying the one that was clicked?  I wouldn't expect `setVisible` to do anything because `vw` never becomes a descendant of a frame.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5):

```
w.particalEmitterImport(xMouse, xMouse);
                                ^^^^^^
```

I think you ment:

```
w.particalEmitterImport(xMouse, yMouse);
                                ^^^^^^
```